# Swift: fastest way to parse HTML

Tags: regex, swift, html-parsing

I have a large file of source code that I need to parse some specific text out of. I want to get it done as fast as possible. What would be the fastest way to do this in Swift? These are all the options I could think of?

- Using a third-party library of string functions- I've tried this. It works well, but I imagine this is much slower compared to other lower level methods in general, unless there are some notably fast ones out there specifically for Swift.
- Using a third-party HTML parser. I've looked into a few, but I'm not sure if they will suit my needs. Before I proceed with this, I just want to know if these are generally faster, if there are any notabley fast ones out there, and if I'm able to tweak them to get specifically what I want from the source code.
- Using String or NSString. From what I understand, using String vs NSString should give no difference in speed. I am quite comfortable with this approach, and it's lower level than some of the other ones, so should I expect fairly fast performance?
- Using regular expressions. I've been told that since these are lower-level, they should ideally be the fastest. I've used regular expressions before, but not in ios. Is it easy to do string parsing with NSRegularExpression, and is it faster?

Thank you!

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/ so relevant to your last point it hurts. Don't use regex

Comment: To expand on iismathwizard's valid point, the reason why html shouldn't be parsed with regexes is that the regular expressions with html just get way too complicated, and become filled with troublesome special characters.

Comment: If you're loading this text into some kind of WebView, it may behoove you to just use JavaScript[Core] to let WebKit handle this for you.  If not, may the gods have mercy on your soul.

Comment: If you are just now starting your journey with Swift, I would recommend you look at other languages that are not specific to just one operating environment.

There are existing scripting languages like Ruby that have wonderful code bases that can accomplish what you want.  Nokogiri would do what you want perfectly and is easy to use.

Mobile development using Ruby is on the horizon.


- For iOS, check out [RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com/)
- For Android, check out [Ruboto](http://ruboto.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Came upon this link while researching your question: http://benedictcohen.co.uk/blog/archives/74

The authors explains an older approach to what @CodaFi suggested, but there is a relevant update at the end you should check out:

> The easiest way to parse HTML is to treat it as XML and use the
>   NSXMLParser. iOS comes with LibTidy which is capable of fixing a
>   multitude of markup sins. Use LibTidy to create clean XML and pass
>   this XML to NSXMLParser. Only use the approach outlined above if it’s
>   not possible to use NSXMLParser.

So perhaps option 4 or 5 for you to check out?